Handling Non-Exact Division in Batch Size For Datasets in CNN
I'm working on a CNN project and need some help with adjusting the steps and batch parameters. Here's a summary of my dataset:
Training images: 5360
Validation images: 1151
Test images: 1147

I have set the following parameters:
Epochs: 20
Batch size: 16

To calculate the steps per epoch, I'm using this code:
nb_train_steps = np.ceil(train_data_gen.samples / batch_size).astype(int)
nb_validation_steps = np.ceil(valid_data_gen.samples / batch_size).astype(int)
nb_test_steps = np.ceil(test_data_gen.samples / batch_size).astype(int)

However, I'm encountering the following error during training:
Epoch 2/20
2024-08-19 01:58:11.161693: I tensorflow/core/framework/local_rendezvous.cc:404] Local rendezvous is aborting with status: OUT_OF_RANGE: End of sequence
         [[{{node IteratorGetNext}}]]
C:\Users\anuja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\contextlib.py:158: UserWarning: Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches. You may need to use the `.repeat()` function when building your dataset.
  self.gen.throw(value)
2024-08-19 01:58:11.190224: I tensorflow/core/framework/local_rendezvous.cc:404] Local rendezvous is aborting with status: OUT_OF_RANGE: End of sequence
         [[{{node IteratorGetNext}}]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\anuja\Desktop\Project\Scripts\model.py", line 140, in <module>
    custom_model.fit(
  File "C:\Users\anuja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\anuja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend\tensorflow\trainer.py", line 354, in fit
    "val_" + name: val for name, val in val_logs.items()
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'

The issue seems to be that the validation and test datasets have a number of images that isn't perfectly divisible by the batch size. For instance:

For the validation set: 1151 / 16 = 71.9375. When rounded up to 72, the program expects an additional image that doesn't exist in the directory.
I anticipate a similar issue with the test set.

I thought about deleting images to make the total number easily divisible by 16 (e.g., reducing 1151 to 1136 so that 1136 / 16 = 71), but this feels wasteful. I'm aware of the .repeat() function, which might help, but I'm unsure how it will affect the model, particularly in terms of overfitting.
Here is my data generation code:
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_data_gen = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=train_path,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical'
)

valid_data_gen = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=val_path,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical'
)

test_data_gen = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=test_path,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=False
)

I do not use any data augmentation because my dataset is fairly balanced.
And here is model.fit():
custom_model.fit(
    train_data_gen,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_steps,
    validation_data=valid_data_gen,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_steps,
    epochs=nb_epochs,
    callbacks=[es, chkpt]
)

My Questions:

How should I handle this situation without deleting any data?
How does using .repeat() impact the model, especially regarding
overfitting?
Are there better approaches to dealing with this issue?

I work with:
TensorFlow version: 2.17.0
Keras version: 3.4.1


What makes you think the problem is non-exact division by batch size? Nothing indicates this as a problem, this has never been a problem. Also you did not mention what Keras version you are using.

Regarding the Keras version, I've updated my question. As for the rest of the issue, I've detailed my thought process in the original question. If there's a different problem beyond what I've described, I would appreciate it if you could clarify the issue and explain me how to resolve it.

what original question? I do not see any thought process about the problem in this question.

If you’re not able to offer constructive assistance or clarify the issue, I suggest you direct your comments elsewhere. I’m looking for practical solutions, not unnecessary criticism. Thank you

It is not criticism, the problem is unclear, and I am asking for clarification, with your comments you are moving away from people answering your question.

I’ve done my best to explain the problem based on my understanding. The error seems related to the dataset running out of data, and I’m not sure if it’s due to non-exact batch size division or another issue. If you find any part of my explanation unclear, please let me know specifically what you need more details on.

At the very least, you need to provide the code for dataset creation and model.fit. Else all we can do is speculate. In general, there should be no need to provide something like steps_per_epoch with finite dataset, as the epoch will simply end when the dataset has been fully iterated over.

I edited the question and added the requested parts of the code.

Data loaders like flow_from_directory() in Tensorflow or DataLoader() in Pytorch generally automatically handle such cases. I think the issue may arise from the fact that you pass your calculated steps explicitly  here validation_steps=nb_validation_steps,, which in fact may not be needed: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/29726

And in case you are training on the CPU, a Batch size as an exponent of 2 is not really mandatory and this apparent "standard" stems from the rise of GPUs which perform better with such a batch size due to their inherent architecture. Hence, you can set some other random number like 49 as a batch size if you want to it would still not lead to  "out of the normal" executions: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/20193

I think I fixed the problem as suggested by @xdurch0 and @rasengan__ I just removed the steps_per_epoch from .fit() and it seems to pass the validation step for each epoch without a problem. Regarding the batch size as an exponent of 2 eventually, I will train it using GPU too. for now I am trying to understand the whole process and then I'm going to use all accessible resources.
